# Ether taking long time to send between my accounts?

Tags: ether

I sent ether from my '`Account 1`' to '`Main account (Etherbase)`' and it has got 0 out of 12 confirmations. It has been about 20 minutes since the transaction was created. I am using the Mist wallet `version 0.8.9`.

Here are the details of the gas used:

```
Fee paid: 0.00042002 ETHER

Gas used:   21,001

Gas price:  0.02 ETHER PER MILLION GAS
```

Transaction Details:

```
Transaction ID: 0x58fb752c8807ed1c5fa46a4a1c17cf37e97f024697e7f1309597f36793‌​76e5a5
```

`Block height: 3367602` (97 block confirmations)

I am wondering what the reason for the delay is for the transaction, or can you not send to the 'Etherbase' account?

Is there somewhere to view the status of the blockchain?

Comment: What's the transaction ID? Did you check if it's known by a block explorer? Also, which wallet are you using?

Comment: Transaction ID is: 0x58fb752c8807ed1c5fa46a4a1c17cf37e97f024697e7f1309597f3679376e5a5
Block height: 3367602 (97 block confirmations)

Comment: I dont see any problem with this. Looks like the transaction went through immediately. Is your Mist wallet maybe not up-to-date? Or did you by any chance send ether to the wrong address?

Answer (score 3):

https://etherscan.io/ is the default ethereum block explorer, from my perspective at least. I know Ethercamp has built one as well. There may be more, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah yea, I just discovered the block explorer when investigating it through the Mist client. Shows it at 24 minutes now but not confirmed... can it be because my fee was too low or because there is too much traffic on the network?

Comment: As long as you signed the transaction, it should have been included already.. Edit: It could be the gas was too low? Did you set the gas to zero? It should of thrown an error, though.

Comment: It looks like it used gas. I put the details on the amount of gas used in the original question now. Says it used 21,002 gas.

I'm wondering if somehow because both of the accounts are held in the same wallet it is the problem?